# Deploy a web app and custom domain using bicep template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

While deploying it to azure portal it's showing an error microsoft.web/serverforms

I have tried to deploy a web app and custom domain to azure portal using arm template. I want to deploy a web app with custom domain.

Comment: Can you provide the template that you have tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- I have deploy a web app with custom domain using below Steps.
- open Azure portal and search for **custom deployment** as  use the below code.

[image]

Thanks `@akhilthomsa011` for arm template.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        },
        "webAppName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the web app that you wish to create."
            }
        },
        "customHostname": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The custom hostname that you wish to add."
            }
        },
        "existingKeyVaultId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Existing Key Vault resource Id for the SSL certificate, leave this blank if not enabling SSL"
            }
        },
        "existingKeyVaultSecretName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Key Vault Secret that contains a PFX certificate, leave this blank if not enabling SSL"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "appServicePlanName": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'),'-asp-', uniquestring(resourceGroup().id))]",
        "certificateName": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'),'-cert')]",
        "enableSSL": "[not(empty(parameters('existingKeyVaultId')))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
            "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "P1",
                "tier": "Premium",
                "size": "1",
                "family": "P",
                "capacity": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "condition": "[variables('enableSSL')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
            "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
            "name": "[variables('certificateName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('webAppName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "keyVaultId": "[parameters('existingKeyVaultId')]",
                "keyVaultSecretName": "[parameters('existingKeyVaultSecretName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/', parameters('customHostname'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "sslState": "[if(variables('enableSSL'), 'SniEnabled', json('null'))]",
                "thumbprint": "[if(variables('enableSSL'), reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))).Thumbprint, json('null'))]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

- Fill the details as shown below and click on **review + Create**.

[image]

- After deployed to azure portal the go to app service and -> custom domain as below.

[image]

[image]

- Reference taken from [Git-Hub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/web-app-custom-domain-and-ssl/azuredeploy.json).